# Download Manger setDestinationToSystemCache() isn't working on API level 23

Tags: android, android-download-manager

When I called request.setDestinationToSystemCache() in an app developed with targetSdkVersion 23 I got following error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid value for destination: 5
```

When I debug I found that the Destination Uri is set to null.

I have added following permission but still not working. It fails when tried to enqueue the 'request' object.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM"/>
```

Any idea why this is happening? Is this can be due to API Level?

Comment: Have you implemented run time permissions .From API level 23 Android system sets permissions dynamically. See this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html